# I face problems when installing Angular CLI v1.4.9

Tags: angular-cli

I got this error while installing Angular CLI

```
C:\Users\user>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...use-db","version":"
1.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-10T15_06_38_9
53Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Looks like there's an issue on GitHub already: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8817. If there's an error in some third-party tool, this isn't something SO can help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command. It worked for me.

`npm cache clean --force`

and then install the CLI.

`npm install -g @angular/cli`